# Solve equation $x \log(x) = k$ for $k > 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve this equation $x \log(x) = k$,
It's easy to show that the function $f(x)=x \log(x) -k$ has a unique solution $f(x)=0$ for $k>2$. But i need to get results about $x$ with a good precision.

Comment: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is a common method to be used.

Comment: $f^{'}(x)=1+\log(x) > 0 \iff x > e^{-1}$, I need to get at least inequalities or some methods to approche $x$.

Comment: If you want a starting interval (although not needed in Newton's method), you can use $[1; k]$.

Comment: @Ertxiem, i need a relation between $x$ and $k$

Comment: Analytical solution : $$x=e^{W(k)}$$ with the Lambert W function. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html . $x(k)$ cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. A special function is required for a closed form solution.

Comment: Thinks @JJacquelin, that's what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k>0$ this equation has the solution

$$x = \exp(\text{W}(k)),$$

in which $\text{W}$ is the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

There are different ways to represent this function. For example, you could use continued fractions, such that you can calculate $\text{W}(k)$ and then $\exp(\text{W}(k)).$

Comment: Thanks, that what i need

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x\log x-k$. By Newton-Raphson Method:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{x_n\log x_n-k}{\log x_n+1}$$

You can compute the solution for required values of $k$. You cannot explicitly find a general solution for any $k$ using numerical methods, the reason specifically for this method is that you need to make an initial "guess" about the value of $x_0$ which you'd be able to do if you have an actual value of $k$ in hand.

As pointed by @PierreCarre choosing $x_0=k$ gives us an iteration sequence that converges very fast to the solution of the equation.

---

For finding the general solution and then approximating using Lambert's $W$-function. Let $x=\exp u$, so we have:
$$\begin{aligned}x\log x&=k\\\exp u\exp \ln u&=k\\ u\exp u &=k \\ u&=W(k)\\ x&=\exp W(k)\\ x&=\dfrac{k}{W(k)}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks, Lambert equation is the way.

Comment: You're welcome. Cheers :))

Comment: Actually, you can check that the conditions for the quadratic convergence of Newton's method are satisfied, for instance, in the interval $[\log k, k]$. Taking $x_0=k$ will generate a sequence converging very fast to the solution of the equation. representing the solution of the equation as the limit of this sequence is not better or worse, more explicit or less explicit, than using W-Lambert's function.

Comment: Thanks @PierreCarre that was really insightful. Cheers :))

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this equation can't be solved analytically but can be well tackled using Newton's method as follows $$x_0=k$$$$x_{n+1}={x_n+{k\over \ln 2}\over 1+\ln x_n}$$We continue iterations as soon as we attain to some precision.